# I'm asked to install KB4461614 (MS Office 32 bit) even though my computer is 64bit, why is that?

Tags: windows, windows-update, microsoft-office-2010, knowledge-base

KB4461614 came out on Jan 8, 2019. It is a security update for MS-Windows Office 32 bits.

Only my computer is MS-Windows 64 bits.

Not only that, I never installed MS-Office, not even the free version.

Why would the OS ask me to install that patch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you may not have installed Office you may have installed another application that used a part of Office in their product.  Windows is seeing that you have something installed that needs an update.

The reason you are being asked to install a 32 bit version of the update is because you have a 32 bit version of Office installed.  The default recommended version of Office to install from Microsoft is actually the 32 bit version.  Just because you have a 64 bit computer does not mean that every application you run is also 64 bit.  That is why you have the "C:\Program Files (x86)" folder on your computer.  These are all of your 32 bit applications.

Basically, if Windows is suggesting to install a Microsoft security patch then you should install it.  If you experience issues afterwards you can go back and uninstall patches.